# Deploying magento on google cloud

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, google-cloud

I want to move my magento site from AWS to Google and I want to make sure Im doing it the right way as I am new with google cloud computing. These are the steps Im planning on doing:

create an instance and install redis and my magento store on it.
create sql for my DB
create a snapshop of this instance
create a template from this snapshot
create a group of instances with the template
create a load balancer and connect it with the instance group

is that the correct way to build a solid and fairly scalable magento site on Google cloud?

are there any other services I can use to make my store even more fast and scalable?

Any suggestions would be welcome (:

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the perfect number to start with is 3 VM:

- 1x web (this would be in a "webserver" group and hit by the loadbalancer)
- 1x admin
- 1x mysql (or CloudSql if your code is higly optimized)

From there, you could scale as much as the mysql can stand